# Скрипт сортирующий файлы по принципу похожести имён

Tags: windows, bat, powershell

Задача такая: из исходной директории раскидать файлы по своим местам.
Суть такова(с):
Скрипт powershell (или батник) парсит файлы в папке A и перемещает их по совпадению хотя бы части имени в папку B, которая имеет готовую иерархию (без подпапок) с именами папок вида "Имя Фамилия" или "Фамилия Имя", или просто "Фамилия", которые частично пересекаются c названиями файлов из исходной директории (A).

Есть идеи как реализовать? =)

Comment: Совпадение части имени с чем?

Comment: Приведите хотя бы пример ЧТО с ЧЕМ сравнивать, и причём тут Имя и Фамилия

Comment: Да, хотел описать максимально подробно, а получилось громоздко и непонятно =)
Есть папка А (source) - со сканами документов, имена которых +/- одинаковые, но в эталонном варианте имеют вид Имя_Фамилия.pdf
А есть папка B (destination) - с папками по каждому сотруднику, которые имеют схожее наименование (заводилось кем-то вручную и поэтому небольшой расколбас либо Имя_Фамилия, либо Фамилия_Имя - в общем нет единообразия)
Файлы А должны попасть в папку B, в директорию конкретного сотрудника. Проблема - что они слегка по-разному называются, но Фамилия почти всегда записана одинаково.

Comment: Папка A - что-то типа Magic Folder получается =))

Comment: С таким подходом Женя Иванов может улететь в Женя Власов. Ведь у них есть совпадение частичное "Женя". Проще руками раскидать, чем придумывать как сопоставлять файлы с каталогами.